# How to get the distinct elements in an array in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with one column of type `array<bigint>` with dynamic size for each row. 
example :

```
          1  [100,200] 
          2  [100,300,500,600]
          3  [200,300]
```

The result should be distinct values from this column of array which should be

```
100
200
300
500
600
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to use `explode(<column name>)`, then apply `distinct` on the subquery, something like:

```
select distinct a.conver from (
  select explode(arr) as conver from arraytype2
) as a
```

You can then use `collect_list` to convert this back to an `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select collect_set(a.expld) from (SELECT explode(arr) as expld FROM data) as a
```

Comment: This returns `[100,200,500,600,300]`, would love to hear the explanation as to how this was select as the correct answer.